# What does it mean by apache httpd having process id but showing as NOT RUNNING

Tags: apache, webserver, httpd.conf

I'm trying to debug an issue, where I started seeing Apache not taking any incoming requests. When I tried to run http://localhost:8080, it did not give me any response. Usually it returns

> "It Works"

.

Then I tried to run apachectl status, and it returned as

> httpd (pid 7629?) NOT RUNNING

What does this really mean, when it has a PID assigned but status showing as NOT RUNNING.

Surprisingly in this scenario, when I tried to hit http://localhost:8080, in some cases it returned

> "It Works"

and in some cases

> "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

What explains this behavior?

I could not find any errors in the apache logs, to determine what may have caused the failure at first place. Any pointers, on what I should look out for ?

Comment: browser cache... use "curl" to test or browser with web console and cache disabled.